# Fetch Last Updated record From MySql

Tags: mysql, jsp

here is my table data and the Query by using that I'm getting data through **JSP**.

```
mysql> select * from allergy;
+---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| allergy | reaction       | note         | email             | time            |
+---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| stomach | Abdominal Pain | ksadjlkah    | xyz@gmail.com | 9/8/17 2:20 PM  |
| fever   | Abdominal Pain | hevy         | xyz@gmail.com | 4/9/17 11:29 AM |
+---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

In similar way I have lots of records under single **EmailID**. But Here is my Question I need To display Last Updated record based on time or whatever. Could any one please help me resolve this issue.
My expected output is

```
   +---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+
    | allergy | reaction       | note         | email             | time            |
    +---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+
    | fever   | Abdominal Pain | hevy         | xyz@gmail.com | 4/9/17 11:29 AM |
    +---------+----------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: once again DB storing date as string? pathological. XY problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the requested output:

```
select * from allergy order by str_to_date(time,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p')    
desc limit 1;
```

Comment: it is XY problem, bad design of column. Only correct solution goes thru conversion. Your solution is slow, never use indexes or similar optimisation on DB server

Comment: Ram BM never can work perfectly. Put more records in database